# G++ compilation : undefined reference to `ATL_<...>' on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors, g++, atlas

I'm trying to compile a program dowmloaded on the Net, using g++ on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. The code uses BLAS/LAPACK & ATLAS :

I get this error during compilation :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dsymm.o): In function `cblas_dsymm':
(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `ATL_dsymm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dsyr2k.o): In function `cblas_dsyr2k':
(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `ATL_dsyr2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dger.o): In function `cblas_dger':
(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `ATL_dger'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dsyr.o): In function `cblas_dsyr':
(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `ATL_dsyr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dsyr2.o): In function `cblas_dsyr2':
(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `ATL_dsyr2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dtrmv.o): In function `cblas_dtrmv':
(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `ATL_dtrmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dtrsv.o): In function `cblas_dtrsv':
(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `ATL_dtrsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dasum.o): In function `cblas_dasum':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_dasum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dnrm2.o): In function `cblas_dnrm2':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_dnrm2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_drot.o): In function `cblas_drot':
(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `ATL_drot'
(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `ATL_drot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_drotg.o): In function `cblas_drotg':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `ATL_drotg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_drotm.o): In function `cblas_drotm':
(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ATL_drotm'
(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ATL_drotm'
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ATL_drotm'
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `ATL_drotm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_drotmg.o): In function `cblas_drotmg':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `ATL_drotmg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dswap.o): In function `cblas_dswap':
(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ATL_dswap'
(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ATL_dswap'
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ATL_dswap'
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `ATL_dswap'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_idamax.o): In function `cblas_idamax':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_idamax'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_sgemm.o): In function `cblas_sgemm':
(.text+0x231): undefined reference to `ATL_ssyrk'
(.text+0x251): undefined reference to `ATL_ssyreflect'
(.text+0x2bf): undefined reference to `ATL_sgemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ssymm.o): In function `cblas_ssymm':
(.text+0x1c1): undefined reference to `ATL_ssymm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ssyr2k.o): In function `cblas_ssyr2k':
(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `ATL_ssyr2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ssyrk.o): In function `cblas_ssyrk':
(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `ATL_ssyrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_strmm.o): In function `cblas_strmm':
(.text+0x1d5): undefined reference to `ATL_strmm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_strsm.o): In function `cblas_strsm':
(.text+0x1d5): undefined reference to `ATL_strsm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_sgemv.o): In function `cblas_sgemv':
(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `ATL_sgemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_sger.o): In function `cblas_sger':
(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `ATL_sger'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ssymv.o): In function `cblas_ssymv':
(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `ATL_ssymv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ssyr.o): In function `cblas_ssyr':
(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `ATL_ssyr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ssyr2.o): In function `cblas_ssyr2':
(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `ATL_ssyr2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_strmv.o): In function `cblas_strmv':
(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `ATL_strmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_strsv.o): In function `cblas_strsv':
(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `ATL_strsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dsdot.o): In function `cblas_dsdot':
(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ATL_dsdot'
(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ATL_dsdot'
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ATL_dsdot'
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `ATL_dsdot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_isamax.o): In function `cblas_isamax':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_isamax'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_sasum.o): In function `cblas_sasum':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_sasum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_saxpy.o): In function `cblas_saxpy':
(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ATL_saxpy'
(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ATL_saxpy'
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ATL_saxpy'
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `ATL_saxpy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_scopy.o): In function `cblas_scopy':
(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ATL_scopy'
(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ATL_scopy'
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ATL_scopy'
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `ATL_scopy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_sdot.o): In function `cblas_sdot':
(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ATL_sdot'
(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ATL_sdot'
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ATL_sdot'
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `ATL_sdot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_sdsdot.o): In function `cblas_sdsdot':
(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ATL_sdsdot'
(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ATL_sdsdot'
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ATL_sdsdot'
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `ATL_sdsdot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_snrm2.o): In function `cblas_snrm2':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_snrm2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_srot.o): In function `cblas_srot':
(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `ATL_srot'
(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `ATL_srot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_srotg.o): In function `cblas_srotg':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `ATL_srotg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_srotm.o): In function `cblas_srotm':
(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ATL_srotm'
(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ATL_srotm'
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ATL_srotm'
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `ATL_srotm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_srotmg.o): In function `cblas_srotmg':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `ATL_srotmg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_sscal.o): In function `cblas_sscal':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_sscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_sswap.o): In function `cblas_sswap':
(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ATL_sswap'
(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ATL_sswap'
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ATL_sswap'
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `ATL_sswap'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zgemm.o): In function `cblas_zgemm':
(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `ATL_zsyrk'
(.text+0x261): undefined reference to `ATL_zsyreflect'
(.text+0x2e4): undefined reference to `ATL_zgemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zhemm.o): In function `cblas_zhemm':
(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `ATL_zhemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zher2k.o): In function `cblas_zher2k':
(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `ATL_zher2k'
(.text+0x415): undefined reference to `ATL_zher2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zherk.o): In function `cblas_zherk':
(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to `ATL_zherk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zsymm.o): In function `cblas_zsymm':
(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `ATL_zsymm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zsyr2k.o): In function `cblas_zsyr2k':
(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `ATL_zsyr2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zsyrk.o): In function `cblas_zsyrk':
(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `ATL_zsyrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ztrmm.o): In function `cblas_ztrmm':
(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `ATL_ztrmm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ztrsm.o): In function `cblas_ztrsm':
(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `ATL_ztrsm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zgemv.o): In function `cblas_zgemv':
(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `ATL_zgemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zgerc.o): In function `cblas_zgerc':
(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `ATL_zmoveConj'
(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `ATL_zgeru'
(.text+0x304): undefined reference to `ATL_zgerc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zgeru.o): In function `cblas_zgeru':
(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `ATL_zgeru'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zhemv.o): In function `cblas_zhemv':
(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `ATL_zmoveConj'
(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `ATL_zscalConj'
(.text+0x22a): undefined reference to `ATL_zhemv'
(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `ATL_zscalConj'
(.text+0x3b6): undefined reference to `ATL_zhemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zher.o): In function `cblas_zher':
(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `ATL_zher'
(.text+0x207): undefined reference to `ATL_zher'
(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `ATL_zmoveConj'
(.text+0x27d): undefined reference to `ATL_zher'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zher2.o): In function `cblas_zher2':
(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to `ATL_zmoveConj'
(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `ATL_zcopyConj'
(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `ATL_zher2'
(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to `ATL_zher2'
(.text+0x3c3): undefined reference to `ATL_zher2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ztrmv.o): In function `cblas_ztrmv':
(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `ATL_ztrmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ztrsv.o): In function `cblas_ztrsv':
(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `ATL_ztrsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dzasum.o): In function `cblas_dzasum':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_dzasum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_dznrm2.o): In function `cblas_dznrm2':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_dznrm2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_izamax.o): In function `cblas_izamax':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_izamax'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zaxpy.o): In function `cblas_zaxpy':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_zaxpy'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_zaxpy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zcopy.o): In function `cblas_zcopy':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_zcopy'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_zcopy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zdotc.o): In function `cblas_zdotc_sub':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_zdotc_sub'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_zdotc_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zdotu.o): In function `cblas_zdotu_sub':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_zdotu_sub'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_zdotu_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zdscal.o): In function `cblas_zdscal':
(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `ATL_zscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zscal.o): In function `cblas_zscal':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_zscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_zswap.o): In function `cblas_zswap':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_zswap'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_zswap'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cgemm.o): In function `cblas_cgemm':
(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `ATL_csyrk'
(.text+0x25b): undefined reference to `ATL_csyreflect'
(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `ATL_cgemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_chemm.o): In function `cblas_chemm':
(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `ATL_chemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cher2k.o): In function `cblas_cher2k':
(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `ATL_cher2k'
(.text+0x3fd): undefined reference to `ATL_cher2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cherk.o): In function `cblas_cherk':
(.text+0x1bd): undefined reference to `ATL_cherk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_csymm.o): In function `cblas_csymm':
(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `ATL_csymm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_csyr2k.o): In function `cblas_csyr2k':
(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `ATL_csyr2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_csyrk.o): In function `cblas_csyrk':
(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `ATL_csyrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ctrmm.o): In function `cblas_ctrmm':
(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `ATL_ctrmm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ctrsm.o): In function `cblas_ctrsm':
(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `ATL_ctrsm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cgemv.o): In function `cblas_cgemv':
(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `ATL_cgemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cgerc.o): In function `cblas_cgerc':
(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `ATL_cmoveConj'
(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `ATL_cgeru'
(.text+0x2f4): undefined reference to `ATL_cgerc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cgeru.o): In function `cblas_cgeru':
(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `ATL_cgeru'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_chemv.o): In function `cblas_chemv':
(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `ATL_cmoveConj'
(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `ATL_cscalConj'
(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to `ATL_chemv'
(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to `ATL_cscalConj'
(.text+0x3a6): undefined reference to `ATL_chemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cher.o): In function `cblas_cher':
(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `ATL_cher'
(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `ATL_cher'
(.text+0x243): undefined reference to `ATL_cmoveConj'
(.text+0x26d): undefined reference to `ATL_cher'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cher2.o): In function `cblas_cher2':
(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `ATL_cmoveConj'
(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `ATL_ccopyConj'
(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `ATL_cher2'
(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to `ATL_cher2'
(.text+0x3c3): undefined reference to `ATL_cher2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ctrmv.o): In function `cblas_ctrmv':
(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `ATL_ctrmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ctrsv.o): In function `cblas_ctrsv':
(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `ATL_ctrsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_caxpy.o): In function `cblas_caxpy':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_caxpy'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_caxpy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_ccopy.o): In function `cblas_ccopy':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_ccopy'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_ccopy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cdotc.o): In function `cblas_cdotc_sub':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_cdotc_sub'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_cdotc_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cdotu.o): In function `cblas_cdotu_sub':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_cdotu_sub'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_cdotu_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cscal.o): In function `cblas_cscal':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_cscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_csscal.o): In function `cblas_csscal':
(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `ATL_cscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_cswap.o): In function `cblas_cswap':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ATL_cswap'
(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ATL_cswap'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_icamax.o): In function `cblas_icamax':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_icamax'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_scasum.o): In function `cblas_scasum':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_scasum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.a(cblas_scnrm2.o): In function `cblas_scnrm2':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `ATL_scnrm2'
```

Here are the libraries I installed as recommeded by the README :

```
sudo apt-get install libfftw3-3 libfftw3-dev liblapack3gf liblapack-dev libatlas-base-dev
```

But `liblapack3gf` is not provided anymore for 18.04, and seems related to this kind of error (https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/394)

Someone has an idea of what the issue is ?

EDIT : The program is [HECTOR](http://segal.ubi.pt/hector/) and I'm trying to compile [version 1.6](http://segal.ubi.pt/hector/hector_1.6_source.tar.bz2)

Comment: »» I'm trying to compile a program ««. Please edit your question to include the name of the "program". And a link, please.

Comment: Program Name and Links added

Comment: Suggest : Use the static package `hector_1.6_static_64bit_Ubuntu16.04.tar.bz2`. ... I have tested the source code with Ubuntu 14.04 - 16.04 - 18.04 and CentOS 6, 32 and 64bits. No luck. Different compiler versions, different versions of `atlas` makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer comes too late, but all you have to do in Ubuntu and his derivatives is to add this: `-lgsl -lfftw3 -lgsl -llapack_atlas -latlas -lcblas` to the line 53 of your Makefile. You should also remove the flag `-static` from line 41.

Both lines should look like this:

```
41: CPPFLAGS= -O3 -fopenm
...
53: ATLAS   = -llapack_atlas -latlas -lcblas -lgsl -lfftw3 -lgsl -llapack_atlas -latlas -lcblas
```